# What are the updated (2013) Facebook URI Schemes for iOS and Android

Tags: android, html, ios, facebook, tablet

I'm working on an application where we need to have the user click on a "Share on Facebook" link/button and launch the Facebook app with the post option (which we can do with fb://composer) and then have the ability to automatically put text in it (so for example we need something like this:

```
<a href="fb://composer?text="Share this item!">Share on Facebook</a>
```

In the past it was possible, but Facebook must have changed their URI/URL schemes. Does anyone have an updated list available? Does Facebook have it somewhere that I am not seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prefilling text is against Platform policies.

Documentation about how to use the native share dialogs can be found here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share-dialog/